# Floating point error in Bigquery POW function

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying a calculation using the formula in BigQuery.

```
SELECT
  B * POW(rank, -A) AS C
FROM
  ...
```

It has been working so far without any issues. Today somewhere in the middle the values become

> POW(858, 109.752)

, and I'm getting the error

```
Floating point error in function: POW(858, 109.752)
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The numbers are too big `select POW(858.0, 105.03)` give 1.27e+308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that I'm reaching that limit of Big Query Power function. So I found an approach that should this job with little cost
You can use Big Query remote functions for exceptional cases handling [ https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions ]

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Y > limit THEN big_query_remote_fun(X,Y) ELSE POW(X,Y) END)
FROM project.dataset.tablename;
```

You can implement the remote function (ie :big_query_remote_fun) in cloud functions using python (basically return pow(a,b) or use some powerful numpy libraries )